# CAS authetication multiple Restful Web Services in SSO

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, cas

I have A SSO environment configured through CAS. When I log into one application and try to access the other application login it will successfully authenticate without credentials. Or, if I make a rest call to the other application when logged in through any of the SSO configured application , I am getting the result while using an application like POSTMAN. But the problem is when I am making a REST call from java back end. Instead of generating a token CAS is redirecting me to the login page... Please, let me know how to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

For web application to backend communication, I will recommend using the proxy mechanism: https://wiki.jasig.org/display/CAS/Proxy+CAS+Walkthrough
The way to configure everything properly depends on the CAS client you use.